# Python, Pairwise 'distance', need a fast way to do it

Tags: python, performance, binary, distance

For a side project in my PhD, I engaged in the task of modelling some system in Python. Efficiency wise, my program hits a bottleneck in the following problem, which I'll expose in a Minimal Working Example.

I deal with a large number of segments encoded by their 3D beginning and endpoints, so each segment is represented by 6 scalars.

I need to calculate a pairwise minimal intersegment distance. The analytical expression of the minimal distance between two segments is found in this [source](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistanceLine3Line3.pdf). To the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
N_segments = 1000
List_of_segments = np.random.rand(N_segments, 6)

Pairwise_minimal_distance_matrix = np.zeros( (N_segments,N_segments) )
for i in range(N_segments):
    for j in range(i+1,N_segments): 

        p0 = List_of_segments[i,0:3] #beginning point of segment i
        p1 = List_of_segments[i,3:6] #end point of segment i
        q0 = List_of_segments[j,0:3] #beginning point of segment j
        q1 = List_of_segments[j,3:6] #end point of segment j
        #for readability, some definitions
        a = np.dot( p1-p0, p1-p0)
        b = np.dot( p1-p0, q1-q0)
        c = np.dot( q1-q0, q1-q0)
        d = np.dot( p1-p0, p0-q0)
        e = np.dot( q1-q0, p0-q0)
        s = (b*e-c*d)/(a*c-b*b)
        t = (a*e-b*d)/(a*c-b*b)
        #the minimal distance between segment i and j
        Pairwise_minimal_distance_matrix[i,j] = sqrt(sum( (p0+(p1-p0)*s-(q0+(q1-q0)*t))**2)) #minimal distance
```

Now, I realize this is extremely inefficient, and this is why I am here. I have looked extensively in how to avoid the loop, but I run into a bit of a problem. Apparently, this sort of calculations is best done with the [cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) of python. However, the custom distance functions it can handle have to be binary functions. This is a problem in my case, because my vectors have specifically a length of 6, and have to bit split into their first and last 3 components. I don't think I can translate the distance calculation into a binary function.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Could an [`octree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), (with [common uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree#Common_uses_of_octrees) mentioning nearest neighbour search on Wikipedia) help here?

Comment: Have you read Lumelsky's [On fast computation of distance between line segments](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/octrope/trunk/doc/lumelsky.pdf) [PDF WARNING]? How does your implementation compare to it? (a more generic approach can be found [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs164-09-spring/Handouts/paper_GJKoriginal.pdf))

Comment: Thank you for the links, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis, I quickly read the paper, this is what I have derived myself analytically. It doesn't say anything about how to accelerate computation specifically. It just outlines a smart way of treating special cases. A good read though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's vectorization capabilities to speed up the calculation. My version computes all elements of the distance matrix at once and then sets the diagonal and the lower triangle to zero.

```
def pairwise_distance2(s):
    # we need this because we're gonna divide by zero
    old_settings = np.seterr(all="ignore")

    N = N_segments # just shorter, could also use len(s)

    # we repeat p0 and p1 along all columns
    p0 = np.repeat(s[:,0:3].reshape((N, 1, 3)), N, axis=1)
    p1 = np.repeat(s[:,3:6].reshape((N, 1, 3)), N, axis=1)
    # and q0, q1 along all rows
    q0 = np.repeat(s[:,0:3].reshape((1, N, 3)), N, axis=0)
    q1 = np.repeat(s[:,3:6].reshape((1, N, 3)), N, axis=0)

    # element-wise dot product over the last dimension,
    # while keeping the number of dimensions at 3
    # (so we can use them together with the p* and q*)
    a = np.sum((p1 - p0) * (p1 - p0), axis=-1).reshape((N, N, 1))
    b = np.sum((p1 - p0) * (q1 - q0), axis=-1).reshape((N, N, 1))
    c = np.sum((q1 - q0) * (q1 - q0), axis=-1).reshape((N, N, 1))
    d = np.sum((p1 - p0) * (p0 - q0), axis=-1).reshape((N, N, 1))
    e = np.sum((q1 - q0) * (p0 - q0), axis=-1).reshape((N, N, 1))

    # same as above
    s = (b*e-c*d)/(a*c-b*b)
    t = (a*e-b*d)/(a*c-b*b)

    # almost same as above
    pairwise = np.sqrt(np.sum( (p0 + (p1 - p0) * s - ( q0 + (q1 - q0) * t))**2, axis=-1))

    # turn the error reporting back on
    np.seterr(**old_settings)

    # set everything at or below the diagonal to 0
    pairwise[np.tril_indices(N)] = 0.0

    return pairwise
```

Now let's take it for a spin. With your example, `N = 1000`, I get a timing of

```
%timeit pairwise_distance(List_of_segments)
1 loops, best of 3: 10.5 s per loop

%timeit pairwise_distance2(List_of_segments)
1 loops, best of 3: 398 ms per loop
```

And of course, the results are the same:

```
(pairwise_distance2(List_of_segments) == pairwise_distance(List_of_segments)).all()
```

returns `True`. I'm also pretty sure there's a matrix multiplication hidden somewhere in the algorithm, so there should be some potential for further speedup (and also cleanup).

By the way: I've tried simply using numba first without success. Not sure why, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I read your first sentence, I thought 'of course', but seeing how the implementation is done, I think you spared me several hours of work : for that I thank you !

As I understand, Numba is based on GPU computing. In your experience, with similar vector sizes (N_segments ~= 1E3-E4), is the overhead to push data onto the graphic card outweighed by the speed-up, or is it impossible to tell until implemented ?

Comment: I very quickly encounter memory issues (N_segments ~= 10k). I'll investigate what is so memory intensive and get back to you (I could have it run on matlab up to 30k)

Comment: @Mathusalem An `N*N` matrix of doubles with `N=10000` takes about 0.75GB of memory. This function creates a bunch of them. My approach would be (since I haven't read enough about the problem to devise a better algorithm) to split the problem into chunks of manageable size and compute them one after another (or even in parallel, if you're inclinded).

Comment: I've also tried extracting the looping part from the program and JIT compile it, but I don't gain any speed. Did you have the same issue ? I suspect

Comment: For your numba comment. I've been digging into it. I think the lack of speed up comes from the fact that there's still not much support for numpy in numba. In particular, numba has difficulties dealing with many numpy functions like numpy.dot, numpy.sqrt, in that it doesn't know the return type of those functions and thus cannot optimize.  Link :  https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/251

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a meta answer, at least for starters. Your problem might already be in "my program hits a bottleneck" and "I realize this is extremely inefficient".

Extremely inefficient? By what measure? Do you have comparison? Is your code too slow to finish in a reasonable amount of time? What *is* a reasonable amount of time for you? Can you throw more computing power at the problem? Equally important -- do you use a proper infrastructure to run your code on (numpy/scipy compiled with vendor compilers, possibly with OpenMP support)?

Then, if you have answers for all of the questions above and need to further optimize your code -- where is the bottleneck in your current code *exactly*? Did you profile it? It the body of the loop possibly much more heavy-weight than the evaluation of the loop itself? If so, then "the loop" is not your bottleneck and you do not need to worry about the nested loop in the first place. Optimize the body at first, possibly by coming up with unorthodox matrix representations of your data so that you can perform all these single calculations in one step -- by matrix multiplication, for instance. If your problem is not solvable by efficient linear algebra operations, you can start writing a C extension or use Cython or use PyPy (which just very recently got some basic numpy support!). There are endless possibilities for optimizing -- the questions really are: how close to a practical solution are you already, how much do you *need* to optimize, and how much of an effort are you willing to invest.

Disclaimer: I have done non-canonical pairwise-distance stuff with scipy/numpy for my PhD, too ;-). For one particular distance metric, I ended up coding the "pairwise" part in simple Python (i.e. I also used the doubly-nested loop), but spent some effort in getting the body as efficient as possible (with a combination of i) a cryptical matrix multiplication representation of my problem and ii) using [`bottleneck`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it something like this:

```
def distance3d (p, q):
    if (p == q).all ():
        return 0

    p0 = p[0:3]
    p1 = p[3:6]
    q0 = q[0:3]
    q1 = q[3:6]

    ...  # Distance computation using the formula above.

print (distance.cdist (List_of_segments, List_of_segments, distance3d))
```

It doesn't seem to be any faster, though, since it executes the same loop internally.