# Inter segment distance using numba jit, Python

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I have been asking related questions on this stack for the past week to try to isolate things I didn't understand about using the @jit decorator with Numba in Python. However, I'm hitting the wall, so I'll just write the whole problem.

The issue at hand is to calculate the minimal distance between pairs of a **large** number of segments. The segments are represented by their beginning and endpoints in 3D. Mathematically, every segment is parameterized as [AB] = A + (B-A)*s, where s in [0,1], and A and B are the beginning and endpoints of the segment. For two such segments, the minimal distance can be computed and the formula is given [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistanceLine3Line3.pdf).

I have already exposed this problem on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693494/python-pairwise-distance-need-a-fast-way-to-do-it/28695050#28695050), and the answer given dealt with replacing double loops of my code by vectorizing the problem, which however would hit memory issues for large sets of segments. Therefore, I've decided to stick with the loops, and use numba's *jit* instead.

Since the solution to the problem requires a lot of dot products, and numpy's dot product is [not supported by numba](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/251), I started by implementing my own 3D dot product.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, autojit, double, float64, float32, void, int32

def my_dot(a,b):
    res = a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
    return res

dot_jit = jit(double(double[:], double[:]))(my_dot)    #I know, it's not of much use here.
```

The function computing the minimal distance of all pairs in N segments takes as input an Nx6 array (6 coordinates)

```
def compute_stuff(array_to_compute):
    N = len(array_to_compute)
    con_mat = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1,N):

            p0 = array_to_compute[i,0:3]
            p1 = array_to_compute[i,3:6]
            q0 = array_to_compute[j,0:3]
            q1 = array_to_compute[j,3:6]

            s = ( dot_jit((p1-p0),(q1-q0))*dot_jit((q1-q0),(p0-q0)) - dot_jit((q1-q0),(q1-q0))*dot_jit((p1-p0),(p0-q0)))/( dot_jit((p1-p0),(p1-p0))*dot_jit((q1-q0),(q1-q0)) - dot_jit((p1-p0),(q1-q0))**2 )
            t = ( dot_jit((p1-p0),(p1-p0))*dot_jit((q1-q0),(p0-q0)) -dot_jit((p1-p0),(q1-q0))*dot_jit((p1-p0),(p0-q0)))/( dot_jit((p1-p0),(p1-p0))*dot_jit((q1-q0),(q1-q0)) - dot_jit((p1-p0),(q1-q0))**2 )

            con_mat[i,j] = np.sum( (p0+(p1-p0)*s-(q0+(q1-q0)*t))**2 ) 

return con_mat

fast_compute_stuff = jit(double[:,:](double[:,:]))(compute_stuff)
```

So, compute_stuff(arg) takes as argument an 2D np.array ( double[:,:]) , performs a bunch of numba-supported (?) operations, and returns another 2D np.array (double[:,:]). However,

```
v = np.random.random( (100,6) )
%timeit compute_stuff(v)
%timeit fast_compute_stuff(v)
```

I get 134 and 123 ms per loop. Can you shed some light on why I fail to speed up my function ? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's *very* unlikely that you'll be able to beat `np.dot` using numba's JIT compiler. `np.dot` is just a thin wrapper that calls BLAS `*gemm/*gemv` functions, which are heavily optimized and often multithreaded. Your best bet is probably to make sure that numpy is linked against the fastest multithreaded BLAS library you can get your hands on (probably either Intel's MKL or OpenBLAS).

Comment: the problem is not beating np.dot, the problem is that if the jit compiler runs into an np.dot call, it cannot infer its return type and then won't speed up my whole function (and btw, dot_jit I coded is faster than np.dot for 3d vector scalar products)

Comment: Have you line-profiled your original code? I suspect that you're spending most of your time inside `np.dot` anyway, so shouldn't expect much performance benefit from JITing away the overhead from the nested `for` loops.

Comment: using cProfile, I see that for 1000 segments, I spend a cumulated time of about 1 second out of 13 in these deep operations (np.dot, np.sum etc)

Comment: OK, looking at your code again I realize that's because you're dotting vectors that are only 2 long! Could you post the line profiling times in your question?

Comment: The vector operations like `p1-p0` and pals are not supported yet according to the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/numpysupported.html#standard-ufuncs): "... ufuncs working on arrays will only compile in nopython mode if their output array is passed explicitly."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my version of your code which is significantly faster:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def dot(a,b):
    res = a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
    return res

@jit
def compute_stuff2(array_to_compute):
    N = array_to_compute.shape[0]
    con_mat = np.zeros((N,N))

    p0 = np.zeros(3)
    p1 = np.zeros(3)
    q0 = np.zeros(3)
    q1 = np.zeros(3)

    p0m1 = np.zeros(3)
    p1m0 = np.zeros(3)
    q0m1 = np.zeros(3)
    q1m0 = np.zeros(3)
    p0mq0 = np.zeros(3)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1,N):

            for k in xrange(3):
                p0[k] = array_to_compute[i,k]
                p1[k] = array_to_compute[i,k+3]
                q0[k] = array_to_compute[j,k]
                q1[k] = array_to_compute[j,k+3]

                p0m1[k] = p0[k] - p1[k]
                p1m0[k] = -p0m1[k]

                q0m1[k] = q0[k] - q1[k]
                q1m0[k] = -q0m1[k]

                p0mq0[k] = p0[k] - q0[k]

            s = ( dot(p1m0, q1m0)*dot(q1m0, p0mq0) - dot(q1m0, q1m0)*dot(p1m0, p0mq0))/( dot(p1m0, p1m0)*dot(q1m0, q1m0) - dot(p1m0, q1m0)**2 )
            t = ( dot(p1m0, p1m0)*dot(q1m0, p0mq0) - dot(p1m0, q1m0)*dot(p1m0, p0mq0))/( dot(p1m0, p1m0)*dot(q1m0, q1m0) - dot(p1m0, q1m0)**2 )


            for k in xrange(3):
                con_mat[i,j] += (p0[k]+(p1[k]-p0[k])*s-(q0[k]+(q1[k]-q0[k])*t))**2 

    return con_mat
```

And the timings:

```
In [38]:

v = np.random.random( (100,6) )
%timeit compute_stuff(v)
%timeit fast_compute_stuff(v)
%timeit compute_stuff2(v)

np.allclose(compute_stuff2(v), compute_stuff(v))

#10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop
#10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
#10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop
#True
```

My basic strategy for speeding this up was:

- Get rid of all array expressions and explicitly unroll the vectorization (especially since your arrays are so small)
- Get rid of redundant calculations (subtracting two vectors) in your calls to the `dot` method.
- Move all array creation to outside of the nested for loops so that numba could potentially do some [loop lifting](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/glossary.html#term-loop-jitting). This also avoids creating many small arrays which is costly. It's better to allocate once and reuse the memory.

Another thing to note is that for recent versions of numba, what use to be called `autojit` (i.e. letting numba do type inference on the inputs) and is now just the decorator without type hints is usually just as fast as specifying your input types in my experience.

Also timings were run using numba 0.17.0 on OS X using the Anaconda python distribution with Python 2.7.9.

Comment: I just tested it for an array of 5000 segments. It brings the execution time from 6 minutes down to 343 milliseconds. I did a bit of reading on the link you provided for loop lifting, and I think I understand everything apart from the first point of your strategy. Why is it faster to explicitly perform the array operations as looped scalar operations?

Since you seem well versed on the topic, for larger arrays, do you think it would speed things up even further to make a cuda implementation (numbapro) of this ?

Comment: I haven't used numba with CUDA via numbapro, so I can't comment on that. As far as my first point of the strategy, currently numba has certain limitations on compiling ufuncs down to native code, which basically involves passing in the output array: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/numpysupported.html#limitations. So it might have been possible to do this with your code, but I chose just to unroll the vectorization by hand.