# numpy.linalg.norm VS scipy cdist for L2 norm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

Very in advance apologies for my basic question!

### **Given**:

```
a = np.random.rand(6, 3)
b = np.random.rand(6, 3)
```

Using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` and `d = cdist(a, b, 'euclidean')`, results in:

```
[[0.8625803  0.29814357 0.97548993 0.84368212 0.66530478 0.95367553]
 [0.67858887 0.27603821 0.76236585 0.80857596 0.48560167 0.84517836]
 [0.53097997 0.41061975 0.66475479 0.54243987 0.47469843 0.70178229]
 [0.37678898 0.7855905  0.25492161 0.79870147 0.37795642 0.58136674]
 [0.73515058 0.90614048 0.88997676 0.15126486 0.82601188 0.63733843]
 [0.34345477 0.7927319  0.52963369 0.27127254 0.64808932 0.66528862]]
```

But `d = np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)`, returns only the diagonal of `scipy` answer:

```
[0.8625803  0.27603821 0.66475479 0.79870147 0.82601188 0.66528862]
```

### **Question**:

Is it possible to get the result of `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` using only `np.linalg.norm` or `numpy`?

Comment: I think `cdist` is probably the best way to calculate this. Unless you have a specific reason for wanting to use numpy?

Comment: You're right! But `scipy` does not have GPU implementation and I figured that `cupy` has `linalg.norm` to calculate  huge vectors / matrices distances!

Comment: Might also be worth checking out [Fastest numba code for computing euclideandistance between a vector and every row of a matrix](https://numba.discourse.group/t/fastest-numba-code-for-computing-euclideandistance-between-a-vector-and-every-row-of-a-matrix/190/12?u=sgbaird) and [How to calculate pairwise distance matrix on the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655878/how-to-calculate-pairwise-distance-matrix-on-the-gpu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as follows:

```py
d = np.linalg.norm(a[:, None, :] - b[None, :,  :], axis=2)
```

Performace should be similar to `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, in my local machine:

```py
%timeit np.linalg.norm(a[:, None, :] - b[None, :,  :], axis=2)
13.5 µs ± 1.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit cdist(a,b)
15 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```